# Where do I put commands that run once at beginning?

Tags: flutter, dart

I really miss C programming. Flutter is quite confusing.

Here is the problem:

We have a function within the Stateful class Home. That creates a page called myMenu.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  myMenu createState() => myMenu();
}

class myMenu extends State<Home>
{


void myProblemFunction(String stringItem) async {

final db =  await myDatabaseClass.instance.database;

 ... 
}
```

Whenever myProblemFunction runs, it will instantiate a new database instance.

I just want to put this command once (i.e.:

```
 final db = await myDatabaseClass.instance.database
```

- ) anywhere in my document (this is my main.dart file (by the way). Now, I could put it in the initState() - sure.. but that's a headache, because a) I would have to make it async, and I feel that will cause me problems, and b) declaring final db... (etc) in the initState() will not make the db variable visible to my functions.

What do I do?

what are the elements in myMenu Class that are triggered? Should I put this function inside the widget build method? But surely if the widget is refreshed, then this function will also be called (again) - I just want to call it once.

Thanks

Comment: If you have some global instance that you want to initialize once, then you could do that in `main()`, just as in C.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `FutureBuilder`

example:

```dart
    FutureBuilder(
      future: myDatabaseClass.instance.database,
      builder: (BuildContext context,AsycnSnapshot snapshot){
             //your code here
      },
    )
```

this will only load the `Future` **once** when the widget is built.

Answer (score 0):

put your code that you want to run only once in initState():

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // TODO code you want to run only once
  }
```